# Token Mismatch Exception in laravel and changing of token for one page and not showing user login info on header

Tags: session, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have been working in laravel for more than 7 months now.Recently I uploaded my project on cpanel and saw that for one page the user login info is not shown and it seems like user is not logged in.Also when trying to add something to cart through session the token mismatch error is shown.

Comment: Maybe some kind of a cache issue. Can you check that the form (specificaly the hidden input _token) is updated correctly. If this part is served from a cache, the token will mismatch. This also explain the other issue regarding session.

Comment: yes i already added the {{csrf_field()}} in laravel. As I already said that the project is working fine on localhost.just having issues in bluehost cpanel

Comment: Yeah I know. That's why I havn't asked if the field is present. But can you check that the actual value is changing on every page load?

Comment: yeah. I am using laravel debugger.I saw that it is showing different token number on one page only.the rest of the pages the token remains the same.    here is the link : http://www.buydsell.com/item/armani-branded-belt-with-100-cotton-material-30.html.  you can check by logging in with username : ma@thissite.com and pw:mehran.  Now when you visit this page you cannot message the person while logged in.and it redirects you to login.

Answer (score 0):

Well my bad.I chose one of the options in bluehosting account that was changing the tokens of laravel application